# It is possible to pass a struct containing an array of structs, which contain arrays, none of which are pointers, as an argument to and OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, struct, opencl, gpgpu

The definitions of my types

```
#define NA 70       
#define NTHR 16

typedef struct {
float
    FSUM[NA],
    ZIJ[NA],
    MASS[NA],
    SUB[NA],
    FMASS[NA*NA],
    FRAC[NA*NA],
    MENT[NA*NA],
    QENT[NA*NA],
    ELIJ[NA*NA],
    SIJ[NA*NA];
} Convect;


typedef struct {
    Convect cpa[NTHR];
} ConvectArray;
```

I want to pass (and retrieve) a `ConvertArray` to an openCL kernel.

I have defined the exact same types in the kernel. I can pass and retrieve, but eventually this code crashes/freezes my machine. When i comment out the setKernelArg, and enqueuReadBuffer for this argument, the code runs again.

Question:

Can I send such a type to and from a kernel but have just made a mistake?

OR

Do I need to just create a `cl_mem` buffer for an array of `convect`?

OR

Something else?

Comment: It looks as if the error is in the code you haven't shown us. My guess would be undefined behavior due to exceeding the bounds of an array somewhere.

Comment: I would say you have a problem at other point in your code. Since that structure should be accepted in OpenCL kernel.

Comment: Please show your `setKernelArg` call and the kernel signature (name and parameter list).